# 403 Access Denied: Table xxx: User does not have permission to query table xxx or perhaps it does not exist in location US

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

To set some context, I am new to GCP/cloud and using CLI but I am a comfortable python user.
I am trying to access BigQuery via Python client and facing the following error:

> 403 Access Denied: Table project_id.dataset.table1: User does not have permission to query table Project_id.dataset.table1, or perhaps it does not exist in location US.

I am sharing the code snippets I used:

Passing credentials:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(Path_to_Json)

project_id = 'project_id'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials = credentials, project=project_id)
```

When I use the following iterator piece of code, it works and shows the list of tables and data sets.

```
# Get an iterator pointing to `DaasetListItem` objects
bq_datasets = client.list_datasets()

# Print BigQuery table and dataset names in project `my-gcp-project`
for dataset in bq_datasets:
  for table in client.list_tables(dataset.dataset_id):
    print(f'{table.table_id=}, {dataset.dataset_id=}, {client.project=}')
```

but when I try to use the creds to query data from any of the tables listed above using the following code, it throws a 403 error:

```
query_job = client.query("""
   SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset.table1` LIMIT 1000""")

results = query_job.result() # Wait for the job to complete.
```

Any guidance and help is highly appreciated!

Things tried:

1. Tried changing the access to the service account in different ways from bigquery user to bigquery data editor via IAM.
2. Checked if the data set is in the US. The dataset location shows in US.